# Best process manager for python programs running in windows environment

Tags: python, windows-server

I need recommendations for software that manages(run as daemon, auto-restart, high-availability) and monitors python scripts running on windows.

I have been primarily using `PM2 or Process Manager 2 [http://pm2.keymetrics.io/]` for nodejs and `python` in the Linux environment and love its capabilities as a `process manager`. 
Is there a good alternative for python programs running on windows environment.
I need high availability of my python scripts in `windows environment` and capability to monitor it over a web/cmd interface.
Alternates I am contemplating are: supervisord, circus

Is PM2 still the best or there is one for python that does a better job on windows environment?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with PM2? It runs on Windows too as far as I know.

Comment: Also, please specify all of your requirements, a person who does not know PM2 (=most people) should be able to answer if they know a program that fits your actual requirements.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul PM2 is nodejs centric which also works for python. I am looking for a similar feature rich software that is python centric and does not depend on nodejs. Also there have been reported issues in the past related to PM2 running on windows (may be its stable with newer versions). If people have good experience working with PM2 on windows then it would make sense to stick to it.

Comment: You wrote "similar feature rich". That means different things for different people. Please express explicitly your requirements, what exact features the software must have. Also, please remove any mention of PM2, if your question is well-defined and PM2 matches then an answer about it might show up. Please do that by editing your question rather than commenting, thanks! :-)

Comment: A bit late, but this could come in handy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404/2557263

Answer (score 0):

You can try nohup which is another process manager. You will be able to run your code in background as well as it also stores log of any occurred event.

Comment: In every Linux I've ever used, nohup is not a process manager, it is a command that launches a programme in the background with a defined configuration.  Can you give  some more details?

Comment: @Chenmunka I agree that the formulation is unlucky. What the OP wants to say, that nohup manipulates other processes. The "process manager" terminology looks to me unclear and windows-ish a little bit.